# print lines as columns two by two

Tags: text-processing, awk

i have this kind of file and i'm searching a way to take just the last 2 columns and print them as one line two by two , can someone give me an idea ! thanks
input:

```
  1     0.00     435.9     6.04
  2     6.04     691.7    27.61
  3    33.65     964.5    10.03
  4    43.68    1932.5
```

output

```
435.9 6.04     691.7 27.61     964.5 10.03    1932.5
```

Comment: Strictly not "last two columns". Where did the 43.68 go? Does "All columns after first column, and all of the same line" express it better?

Comment: 43.68 for me is a part of second column so we have 1932.5 and no vaue in 4th column !

Comment: "Can someone give me an idea?" Yes. Use awk to read the fields you want, use awk's `printf` function to print them without a newline. If you have trouble, please [edit] the question with your attempt, we will be sure to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somethis like this?

```
awk '{printf ("%s %s\t", $3, $4)}' file
```

or maybe like this to handle the missing fields

```
awk '{field3=$3; field4=$4} $3==""{field3="\t"} $4==""{field4="\t"} {printf ("%s %s\t", field3, field4)}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an `awk-paste` pipeline we print the third and fourth fields, separated by a single space, and then they all get thrown onto a single line by  `paste`'s `-s` option, with each pair separated by the `paste`'s default delimiter `TAB=\t`.

```
$ awk '{print $3, $4}' file | paste -s -
```

If we want to stay within `awk`, that is also possible:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { s[1] = "\t"; ORS = "" }
    { print s[(NR>1)] $3, $4 }
    END { print RS }
' file
```

We can also do a `cut-paste` job of it, but before that a small edit has to be done, viz., transmuting all whitespace to a space, squeeze multiple spaces, and strip leading space (if any). This is due to `cut` requiring a single char as delimiter and cut does not ignore leading delimiters.

```
$ < file sed -Ee 's/\s+/ /g;s/^ //' |
    cut -d' ' -f3,4 | paste -s -
```

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
m=re.compile(r'\s{1,}')
t=[]
k=open('file.txt','r')
for i in k:
    j=re.sub(m," ",i)
    try:
        o=j.strip().split(' ')
        if (len(o) == 4):
            y="{0} {1}".format(o[2],o[3])
        elif (len(o) == 3):
            y="{0}".format(o[2])
        else:
            print "Number of columns is less than 3"
        t.append(y)

    except:
        pass

print "\t".join(t)
```

output

```
 python test.py 
435.9 6.04  691.7 27.61 964.5 10.03 1932.5
praveen@praveen:~
```

$

awk command

```
awk '{print $3,$4}' filename| perl -pne "s/\n/\t/g"
```

435.9 6.04  691.7 27.61 964.5 10.03 1932.5